# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity$2

Tags: java, android, javafxports

Getting the following error when starting my application on Android Phone

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ie.murphysoftware.games.magnatron, PID: 17378
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity$2
    at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.jfxEventsLoop(FXDalvikEntity.java:484)
    at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.<init>(FXDalvikEntity.java:118)
    at javafxports.android.FXActivity.onCreate(FXActivity.java:140)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error shows when running the app on Android Version KitKat API Level 19 and possibly lower versions of Android.

There are 2 dex classes in the APK

- classes.dex
- classes2.dex

The problem seems to be that the primary dex file **classes.dex** contains the class **FXDalvikEntity** and **classes2.dex** contains it's sub-classes which are

- FXDalvikEntity$1
- FXDalvikEntity$2
- FXDalvikEntity$InternalSurfaceView
- FXDalvikEntity$InternalTextureView
- FXDalvikEntity$SurfaceDetails

When the application starts the classes contained in **classes.dex** are loaded but the classes from **classes2.dex** are not and this causes the error.

> Is there a way to force dex to only create one dex file?

My build environment is

```
Eclipse - Neon
Gradle 3.1
compileSdkVersion = 25
minSdkVersion = 17
buildToolsVersion = "25.0.0"
applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.ensemble'
```

Comment: Do you have `multiDexEnabled = true`?

Comment: Yes, and the application apk has multiple dex files. The problem as I described above is getting the 2nd dex file classes loaded by the application.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue with Android API >= 21 ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha - No, I've only been able to cause this issue on API 19., it works on API >= 21.  I would think it will fail on API 19 or less.

Comment: Can you [create an issue](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/issues) for the same in JavaFXPorts repository?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha - I've added the issue as you suggested, although I'm not sure that it's a suitable question for that site.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in JavaFXPorts and needs to be reported.

Comment: No, its not a bug in javafxports.  The issue is with the construction of the APK as I've said in the details included in the question.

Comment: What I find curious is, that I don't have the issue. I've just checked: I've got multiple dex files, minSdk set to 19 - and it works (on a Nexus 5 with Android 6, to be fair).

Answer (score 0):

This is what the exception your receive indicates:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

(source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

This means, that the class being accessed (directly or indirectly) in your app does not exist in the runtime environment. So probably, you need to choose a newer version as your runtime environment. An alternative cause might be that dependencies you use are not there (I am not sure how Android applications deal with 3rd party dependencies) and you need to include them to your application.

Comment: This issue is Android dex class loading related and while the answer you have given is correct when related to java class loading it does not address the question I asked.

Comment: I see. I digged into the "multiple dex files" issue and this seems to be a problem of the API version your are using. Prior to API version 21, you are limited to 1 DEX file (unless you use extra dependencies for multi-dex files). As of API 21, you can have multiple DEX files (I see in your comments you have verified that yourself already).

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a solution yet but the cause of the issue is.

1. The size of the application requires 2 dex files.
2. Android SDK version 20 or less does not support multidex files naturally and requires an additional android library "multidex.jar".  Implementing the multidex library requires additional code which is documented in detail at this link [Using multidex when minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)
3. These detailed instructions do not consider the javafxports hierarchy and require that the class needed to implement the multidex functionality `extends android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` or overrides the `Application.attachBaseContext(...)`.

So the solution now seems to be to find a way to have the `javafx.application.Application` call the `Multidex.install(this);` leading to a new questioon on stackoverflow [javafxports multidex minSdkVersion is set to 20 or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415455/javafxports-multidex-minsdkversion-is-set-to-20-or-less)

Comment: I don't know your manifest and gradle build, but multidex is - AFAIK - activated per default in JavaFXMobile. So you'd need the (__fully qualified!__) MultiDexApplication name set to the manifests `<application name=""><!-- ... --></application>`.