# javafxports multidex minSdkVersion is set to 20 or less

Tags: java, android, javafxports

Researched the cause identified in this issue [Link to initial cause of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393148/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafxports-android-fxdalvikentity2).  The solution is to implement the required use of the android multidex library on android sdk versions 20 or less.

The issue now is how to implement the solution detailed at this link [Using multidex when minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Extract from link.

> If you do override the Application class, change it to extend
>   MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:
>
> ```
> public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
> ```
>
> Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to
>   change the base class, then you can instead override the
>   attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable
>   multidex:
>
> ```
> public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
>   @Override
>   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
>      super.attachBaseContext(context);
>      Multidex.install(this);
>   }
> }
> ```

The full package names for the classes mentioned in the above code are

```
android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
android.app.Application
```

The javafx application extends `javafx.application.Application`

The question is - how to implemented the multidex solution when extending `javafx.application.Application` when using javafxports?

Now including the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ie.murphysoftware.games.magnatron"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="5.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/magnatron_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data android:name="launcher.class" android:value="javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher" />
            <!-- Full name of the application class to run -->
            <meta-data android:name="main.class"
                android:value="ie.murphysoftware.games.magnatron.MagnatronStart" />
            <!-- Jvm arguments (delimiter |) -->
            <meta-data android:name="jvm.args"
                android:value="-Djavafx.verbose=true|-Djavafx.name=value" />
            <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <!-- Application arguments (delimiter |) -->
            <meta-data android:name="app.args" android:value="arg1|arg2" />
            <!-- Jdwp debugging port. Don't forget to forward port (adb forward tcp:port1 tcp:port2) -->
            <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't need the explicit MultiDexApplication (very often) in real life scenario. Normaly it's ok to just enable multidexing on Android. And again: As far as I know, this is already activer per default in the javafxports plugin. Can you elaborate, why you need to extend MultiDexApplication? And by the way: If you want to use another then the default Android `Application` you have to specify this in the Android Manifest: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm (attribute "name").

Comment: @dzim See the section titled "Multidex support prior to Android 5.0" on this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html.  Note that I've included this link in my question.

Comment: Ok, I get __this__ part (I did indeed read not enough of the Android Dev page). But then, you are asking, how to use the Android `MultiDexApplication` class, when you have a JavaFX `Application` class. The Answer is: No problem, there are totally separated. Create a class `MultiDexApplication` and set it into the Android Manifest. They are totally different things and you don't need to do something to the JavaFX application. Just the Android specific application is needed. Can you try that? Or should I post an answer with my suggested solution (which it hopefully is :-D )?

Comment: Can you update your question and provide us the Android manifest? And Gradle build?

Comment: @dzim - The issue is that to load multiple dex files for android sdk version 20 or lower requires that you implement the multidex library.  This must be implemented by overriding MultiDexApplication or Application.  How can I override either using the AndroidManifest that I've now included in the question.

Comment: When did you create your project? As it was state somewhere either in an issue on BitBucket or here on StackOverflow: "MultiDex is enabled by default". This is implemented into the JavaFXMobile Gradle and IDE plugins. This means, when you create a new project with the IDE, the AndroidManifest will reflect that, and it will activate it on its Gradle dependencies as well. This (https://github.com/bgmf/example/blob/master/ExampleProject/src/android/AndroidManifest.xml) is a example project by me. I needed to discus an issue with one of the JavaFXPorts devs there => _MultiDex = enabled_

Comment: if you want: I can create an answer based on the example project, what do you say?

Comment: If you can make it work with SDK <= 20 then by all means.  To prove it works you will need 2 or more .dex files in the APK and that JavaFX works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on an example project, I needed to create in Order to solve an issue with the UI rendering. Initially it was really slow and took up to 7s (2s FXML parsing, approx. 5s frozen UI) on my Nexus 6 and is now down to approx. 2.5s.

Here's the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="eu.dzim.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application android:label="ExampleProject" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="ExampleProject" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                    <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="eu.dzim.example.Main"/>
                    <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Note:** `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` on the `<application>` tag.

The Gradle file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
    url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'eu.dzim.example.Main'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0'

    compile 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.12'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:8.13'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialdesignfont:1.7.22'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.4'

    compileNoRetrolambda 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
    version = '3.1.0'
    plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'settings'
    }
    android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    minSdkVersion = 19
    targetSdkVersion = 22
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize '2g'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        pickFirst 'license/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    }
}
```

I created the Android/Desktop set-up with the IDE plugin for Eclipse (but this should not matter).

I just-rechecked it, build it and verified, that there were two dex files in `build/javafxports/tmp/android/dex`:

- classes.dex
- classes2.dex

I triggered the build via the task `androidInstall` and the app run as expected on a Nexus 5 test device.

**So please:** Compare those files with your set-up. Try to build and install it. As I said: It works fine for me...

---

Additionally I read on some other post here on StackOverflow, that one solved a dex-issue by simply using the correct JDK (64bit instead of 32bit). So make sure, your set-up beside the Gradle and Manifest is ok as well.